# Storing username and password in Android app

Tags: android, security, authentication

I need to store user credentials in my Android app. The application sends HTTP requests to a server and the credentials are used to authenticate with that server.

I know that many articles and many discussions about this topic already exist. However, I would like to ask for help considering the following specific requirements:

- The user should be asked to type username and password just once. After that, the application must be able to authenticate with the server forever.
- If the server receives an authentication request that contains username and password, it generates a random token and sends it back to the client.
- The client must add the token to other requests (as an HTTP header).
- The validity of the token always expires an hour after it was generated. The client must send another authentication request with username and password to get a new token.

Note that the server provides a custom authentication mechanism that does not follow any standard.

I would say that these are very strong requirements and that they already impact some security issues. However, let's suppose that these conditions cannot be changed and that they must be met by the Android app.

Here is what I am going to do:

- As the user should provide credentials just once per app installation and as the token on the server side has a limited validity and the client must re-authenticate with the credentials again and again, the Android app cannot avoid storing the password.
- I will store the credentials into DB (by subclassing `SQLiteOpenHelper` from the `android.database.sqlite` package).
- I will encrypt the credentials before storing them but the key used for encryption/decryption will be just a constant hardcoded in the app.
- Additionally I will set `android:allowBackup` to `false` in the manifest file and obfuscate the application.

I know that an attacker with physical access to the device can get the credentials. I am also aware that some of the suggested steps are just little obstacles for such attacker.

However, is there something more I can do to improve security if there are the requirements mentioned at the beginning of the question?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have to go down this route, I do not know Android security so I cannot comment on that.  One thing of the top of my head.  The encryption key that you will be using, do not hard code it, it would be ideal to have a different key per user, that way if one device gets compromised and the key is found out, it cannot be used to attack another users device.  I am sure there is TON more that can be done, I will have to think about this more.

Comment: @SBurris Using different keys for different users makes a good sense. In such case, I would have to generate the key either in a deterministic way or generate a random key. If the key is deterministic (e.g. derived from the device ID), an attacker can decompile the app and find the algorithm which builds the key. If the key is random, it must be stored somewhere. However, if an attacker is able to find the stored password, he is also able to find the stored key. Which option do you think is better? Or have I overlooked something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I would use [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) to store the user credentials. This is a simple way to create and use an encrypted (using AES) `sqlite` database with minimal hassle.

Of course, this doesn't solve the whole problem. You still need a secure way of generating/storing the key to said database. If I were to recommend any option, I would advise requiring users to input a password/PIN whenever they open the app, and use said password/PIN as the database key.

An alternate method would be to generate a unique, random key upon app installation, and store it in [the Android Keystore](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). A truly dedicated/well-funded attacker would still be able to retrieve the key, but only for the database on that one device.

Comment: I have already considered using SQLCipher before. It's an option but I have decided not to use it finally. If the username-password pair is the only thing to be stored, I prefer encrypting this single value manually rather than having dependency on another library.

Comment: Requiring users to input credentials whenever they open the app (or at least when the token expires) is generally a good idea and I agree with it. Unluckily, providing the credentials only once per app installation is a "must have" requirement in this case.

Comment: Using the Android Keystore would make a good sense. (+1) However, it seems that it requires API level 18 and I must address API level 16 (or at least 17).

Comment: In that case, you might want to read [this article](https://www.cs.ru.nl/E.Poll/papers/AndroidSecureStorage.pdf) on a collection of different key-storage strategies on Android devices. It goes into far more depth and rigor than I could in this space.